# Errors with libexa when compiling xorg-server

Tags: gcc, makefile, xorg

I am trying to compile the xorg-server version 1.20.5.

```
LDFLAGS="-lrt" ./configure \
  --prefix=/usr \
  --enable-glamor \
  --enable-config-udev \
  --enable-config-udev-kms \
  --enable-suid-wrapper \
  --disable-systemd-logind \
  --with-xkb-output=/lib/xkb \
  --with-log-dir=/var/log/xorg
```

Configure gives no errors, but when running make, I get this:

```
gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/examodule.o  -Wl,--whole-archive ../../../exa/.libs/libexa.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -lrt /usr/lib/libpixman-1.a -lm  -g -O2 -pthread   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libexa.so -o .libs/libexa.so
/usr/sbin/ld: /usr/lib/libpixman-1.a(pixman-implementation.o)(.text+0x2c8): R_ARM_TLS_LE32 relocation not permitted in shared object
/usr/lib/libpixman-1.a(pixman-implementation.o): in function `_pixman_implementation_lookup_composite':
/home/root/pixman-0.38.4/pixman/pixman-implementation.c:180:(.text+0x2c8): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [Makefile:699: libexa.la] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/root/xorg-server-1.20.5/hw/xfree86/exa'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:749: all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/root/xorg-server-1.20.5/hw/xfree86/exa'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:869: all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/root/xorg-server-1.20.5/hw/xfree86'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:678: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/root/xorg-server-1.20.5/hw/xfree86'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:615: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/root/xorg-server-1.20.5/hw'
make: *** [Makefile:816: all-recursive] Error 1
```

How do I fix this? I assume I need some custom LDFLAGS? What is libexa anyways? Do I really need it or can I disable it somehow?

Comment: From the looks like you are trying to build for ARM. Are you running the build on x86_64 or ARM ?

Comment: I am building on ARM.

Comment: gnueabihf to be exact, so 32bit ARM.